# Fix geometry to run pgr_createTopology which is very slow and fails

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, pgrouting, routing

I'm trying to create topology in PostgreSQL using pgr_createTopology but it's very slow and fails after processing 4000 nodes. There are 300,000 nodes. I tried the same query with another road table (with 1,200,000 nodes) and it worked well. I compared tables and all parameters were the same. Then I used QGIS to fix geometry, uploaded the table to PostgreSQL, and worked fast enough. Is there any way to fix geometry directly in PostgreSQL?
I tried:

```
UPDATE public.valid_mytable
SET geom=ST_MakeValid(geom);
```

This approach doesn't work.

Filter with "rows_where := " doesn't make sense as a larger table with correct geometry works perfectly.

Comment: ```
UPDATE public.valid_mytable
SET geom=ST_MakeValid(geom);
This approach doesn't work.
```
Need a bit more information. What was the error? 
You ask if there is a way to fix geom in Postgis. The function you are using is good, it is a bit better in new versions of Postgresql / Postgis. What version are you on?

Comment: @BJW "This approach doesn't work." means the result was the same, pgr_createTopology query was slow. ST_MakeValid didn't help. I tried many things and finally, split road nodes with ST_Dump helped and fastened the process.